# Do PHP headers really prevent the client from caching?

Tags: php, ajax, http, caching, http-headers

I've always sent a bunch of headers when I didn't want the client to cache the results.  I've recently read that they don't always work for all browsers, and that appending a random number (or datetime, etc) is the only sure way.  Do PHP headers really prevent the client from caching?  Should I instead append a changing value in the URL?

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
```

Comment: depends on the client, and there are thousands of them

Comment: @Dagon.  So the answer is "No"?

Comment: As a first step, I'd remove those Cache-Controls which are both non-standard and deprecated by the vendor who invented them.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the answer to your question but might help!**

double check if the problem you are solving can be rewritten so not only caching will not be an issue but it would also help your program to run faster.

for example. lets say we have mypics.php a user can choose between 3 different pictures:

pic1.jpg , pic2.jpg , pic3.jpg

and later you want to show their chosen pic (say pic1.jpg).

instead of copying pic1.jpg to a folder or database and call it selectedPic.jpg which makes caching issues if the user change the pic just store the link to the pic1.jpg

Good luck!